# ArrayFormula COUNTUNIQUE

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

How would I turn this formula into an array formula so it automatically populated when a new row is created? `=countunique(Z23:AC23)`

I need the formula to count the unique properties in a row between cells Z-AC for every new row it creates.

For example, when row 24 has info entered it, I need the formula to automatically run: `=countunique(Z24:AC24)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a range of Z2:AC, try the following in row 2:

```
=index(iferror(1/mmult(floor(iferror(1/countifs(
Z2:AC,Z2:AC,
if(column(Z2:AC),row(Z2:AC)),if(column(Z2:AC),row(Z2:AC)),
if(row(Z2:AC),column(Z2:AC)),"<="&if(row(Z2:AC),column(Z2:AC))))),
transpose(column(Z2:AC))^0)^-1))
```

[image]